# Customising Firebase Crashlytics crash reports

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, crashlytics

I am trying to customise Firebase Crashlytics reports by adding a couple of custom keys. I followed instructions from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios

The iOS app is based on React Native. I have added dollowing in one of the methods of `RNSPlashScreen.m`:
`[[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] setCustomValue:templateVersion forKey:@"template_version"];`

But I get following error:
*Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRCrashlytics'*

I tried adding:
`@import FirebaseCrashlytics;`

But then another error popped up:
*Module 'FirebaseCrashlytics' not found*

Although I can confirm that I have followed all steps as mentioned in the documentation and I am able to get the crash reports in Firebase console. I have also added `use_frameworks!` in my podfile.

I am facing issues in adding customer keys for the more detailed reporting. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like your app is not finding the FirebaseCrashlytics library, so it can't make sense of `@import FirebaseCrashlytics;` or `[[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] setCustomValue:templateVersion forKey:@"template_version"];`. Try totally deintegrating Crashlytics and reintegrating it as per the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work. Let me start by saying, I'm a newbie in iOS development. I was adding the tracking code in SplashScreen which was the primary concern I believe. I moved it to RootView class and it solved the issue.

About the import error, Replacing `@import FirebaseCrashlytics;` with `#import "FIRCrashlytics.h"` did the trick.

Let me know if anyone has any suggestion or comment on the same.